# Docker Jenkins Integration

Tags: maven, jenkins, docker

i deployed jenkins as docker container. Created a job to build and push docker image as maven project. But when tried to build the it ends up in error.

```
    [INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (build-service-docker-image) @ infyDockerImageTomcat8 ---
[INFO] Executing tasks
     [echo] Running [docker build -t hi2vaisakh/infy-poc-tomcat8:v1.0 .]
     [exec] /bin/sh: 1: docker: not found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to mount the docker sockets from your host machine into your jenkins container if you want to use the docker commands in Jenkins. Something like this should work:

```
docker run -d \
     -u root \
     -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
     -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker:ro \
     -v /lib64/libdevmapper.so.1.02:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdevmapper.so.1.02 \
     -v /lib64/libudev.so.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0 \
     -p 8080:8080 \
     --name jenkins \
     --privileged=true -t -i \
jenkins
```

Comment: wow it got worked thanks a lot. But when i run docker info command it's showing error " error while loading shared libraries: libdevmapper.so.1.02: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: That's something which is OS-specific I think: For example on CentOS I had to perform: -v /lib64/libdevmapper.so.1.02:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdevmapper.so.1.02 \ . I also had to mount -v /lib64/libudev.so.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0 \

Comment: You have to check the path to your libdevmapper.so.1.02. on your server. I don't know if this path is OS (Centos/Ubuntu/...) specific.